# jstatd does not exist

Tags: java, tomcat, profiler, jstatd

I am running Tomcat 6.0 in my Ubuntu server.

Recently I noticed there is a possibility of memory leak.

So I want to use Java Memory Profiler.

But I can't find 'jstatd' in my $JAVA_HOME.
I am using java-6-openjdk-amd64 and existing files are as follows:

> java  java-rmi.cgi  keytool  orbd  pack200  rmid  rmiregistry 
>   servertool  tnameserv  unpack200

I tried to install jstatd, but I couldn't find a way. (The reason is that it normally exists if you have java, I guess.)

How can I use it?

Comment: It's Oracle's thing. It doesn't exist in openjdk.

Comment: Oh Thanks. But then how can I use it??

Comment: By using Oracle's JDK instead of openjdk.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try later because it is live server... And sorry for late answer.